# Google News sitemap

Tags: wordpress, sitemap, google-news

I run a cricket website, built in wordpress, that has been accepted in Google News but I need to submit an XML sitemap via Webmaster Tools to get my articles appearing.

I have created a very simple sitemap (see code below) that I hope will do the trick but the question is:

** Where to upload it in my file directory?**

Simple enough you would think but many seem to use plugins to generate sitemaps with wordpress sites and I rarely edit files.

The outcome I want is: http://cricketyorkshire.com/newssitemap.xml

Thanks!

--

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9"
        xmlns:news="http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap-news/0.9">
  <url>
    <loc>http://www.example.org/business/article55.html</loc>
    <news:news>
      <news:publication>
        <news:name>Cricket Yorkshire</news:name>
        <news:language>en</news:language>
      </news:publication>
      <news:genres>PressRelease, Blog</news:genres>
      <news:publication_date>2015/07/16</news:publication_date>
      <news:title>How does the month of Ramadan affect cricketers? </news:title>
      <news:keywords>cricket, ramadan, religion, sports, yorkshire</news:keywords>
      </news:news>
  </url>
</urlset>
```

Comment: Put it directly in your WP site root, right next to *wp-config.php*

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I did as suggested and it seems to be there at http://cricketyorkshire.com/newssitemap.xml

However, testing the sitemap with Google Webmaster Tools has this error:

'We encountered an error while trying to access your Sitemap. Please ensure your Sitemap follows our guidelines and can be accessed at the location you provided and then resubmit.'

Any ideas? It could obviously be the sitemap is wrongly configured or it's in the wrong place but I don't think that's the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sitemap can be anywhere on the site, it really doesn't matter, but the most convenient place is probably the root of your site, next to your wp-config.php as others suggested.

Google News sitemaps should be updated every single time you publish an article, otherwise it doesn't make sense to have it. Moreover, if you don't submit an always up-to-date sitemap, we will have a hard time discovering your content, AND we might not even be able to discover them at all if you don't have numbers in your URLs (that don't resemble a date)

> Display a three-digit number. The URL for each article must contain a unique number consisting of at least three digits. For example, we can't crawl an article with this URL: `http://www.google.com/news/article23.html`. We can, however, crawl an article with this URL: `http://www.google.com/news/article234.html`. Keep in mind that if the only number in the article consists of an isolated four-digit number that starts with 199 or 200, we won't be able to crawl it. Please note that this rule is waived with News sitemaps.

If you're using wordpress you can simply install a plugin that will generate the sitemap for you, I created such plugin, it works great for many people. To see all `google news sitemap` related plugins, see
https://wordpress.org/plugins/search.php?type=term&q=google+news+sitemap

Comment: thanks for the reply. Your input matches that of an email from Google News who said to either start implementing numbered URLs or submit a GN sitemap. I use Yoast SEO plugin but haven't paid for their Google News version, preferring instead to have a go and creating and submitting my own. Given it needs to be updated all the time, I can see why the automated plugin route is preferred.

I will start using numbered URLs and can you also tell me your plugin (publicly or privately) and I will also take a look.

Comment: You can just pick one from their repository, most of them are working fine. Look for the highest rated one, no need to use mine.

Comment: Will take a look - out of interest - with numbered URLs from now on, I'm working to the basis that I either pick a random number for the URL, ie) http://cricketyorkshire.com/4546754 upwards or change the permalink structure in wordpress which obviously is very messy and involves redirects etc. My current URL structure is domain.com/post title so I won't in future have the title keywords in the URL string (beneficial for SEO I believe) but it works for BBC news so can't be such an issue?

Answer (score 0):

If you have this file available as xml file, simply upload it to the root of your WP install, that is the top level where you typically find wp-config too. From there you can access it directly in the browser, similar to what WMT and bots would do.

Comment: Sylvia - thanks for the answer. I did that and it seems to be there at